JetPack Compose -- Why DragAndDropSource transferdata does not reflect new state after recomposition?
I have a list of items, each of which uses Modifier.draganddropsource to publish a ClipData for some targets within the same screen. When an item is dropped on a target, it is removed from the original list and the list recomposes. It all looks fine on the screen (new list is drawn with that item spliced out). But, when I go to drag the next item on the list -- below the one I just took out -- its ClipData still represents the previous (removed) item, and the target thinks it is getting the old item again.
The Source composable:
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ItemView(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    item: String
) {

val clipState: String by remember(item) {
    derivedStateOf { item }
}

//    val transferData:  suspend DragAndDropSourceScope.() -> Unit by remember(item) {
//        Log.d("ItemView", "recomposing derived draganddrop for $item")
//
//        derivedStateOf {
//            {
//            detectTapGestures(onPress = {
//                Log.d("Source", "starting to drag ${item}")
//                startTransfer(DragAndDropTransferData(
//                    ClipData.newPlainText("product", item),
//                    flags = View.DRAG_FLAG_OPAQUE
//                ))
//            })
//
//        }}
//    }

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            //.dragAndDropSource(block = transferData)
            .dragAndDropSource {

                detectTapGestures(onPress = {
                    Log.d("Source", "starting to drag ${item}")
                    startTransfer(DragAndDropTransferData(
                        ClipData.newPlainText("product", item),
                        localState = clipState,
                        flags = View.DRAG_FLAG_OPAQUE
                    ),
                    )
                })
        }
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(48.dp),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
) {
    Text(
        text = item,
        color = Color.Black
    )
}

}
The Target callback:
class Callback(val index: Int): DragAndDropTarget {
   ...

    override fun onDrop(event: DragAndDropEvent): Boolean {
        return try {
            event.toAndroidDragEvent().localState.also {  Log.d("Target", "localState: $it") }
            event.toAndroidDragEvent().clipData.getItemAt(0).text.toString()
                .also {
                    Log.d("Target", "drop $it to $index")
                    onDrop(index, it)
                }
            insertIndex = null
            true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("DropCallback", "failed parse data", e)
            false
        }
    }
...
}

You can see in the comments, I did try to keep the TransferData and then the whole source block in a remembered state keyed off of the item, but this had no effect. I couldn't figure out how to keep the onPress function that way.
The item does change, because the composable on screen shows the correct text. But every log statement in source and target reflect the old state of this composable, EXCEPT the "recomposing derived draganddrop" one, which shows the correct new item (all of the remaining items are recomposed after when the list changes, this is just a map function not LazyColumn). Interestingly, all of the items elsewhere in the list work correctly -- only the one item below where the list changed has this problem, but it does persist so that as you move more items, more of the remaining have the wrong data. Anyway, I'm not an expert on state and recomposition, etc, so I'm hoping you can point out something I've overlooked. Thanks
